# Error in fmincon "Error using parfinitedifferences"

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm using fmincon and it gives an error when I run it. The error is:

> Error using parfinitedifferences Distance between lower and upper
>   bounds, in dimension 24 is too small to compute finite-difference
>   approximation of derivative. Increase distance between these bounds to
>   be at least 0.1.
>
> Error in parfinitedifferences
>
> Error in computeFinDiffGradAndJac
>
> Error in barrier

What is the reason of this kind of error and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I would guess the reason is because you bounds are too close (i.e. less than 0.1 difference) in the 24th dimension, as clearly stated in the error message. If you don't post your code then how can anyone tell you why it errored?

Comment: try always showing a [mcve]